# Deploy NodeJS App to Elastic Beanstalk Docker Platform from VSCode?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an NodeJS app that I am deploying to AWS Elasticbeanstalk Docker Platform. For now, i just upload and deploy .zip file while logged in to AWS. I am wondering if there is a more efficient streamlined way to accomplish that directly from VSCode.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a toolkit available from the extension marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-toolkit-vscode

#### Steps to install

(Taken from their official site: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/setup-toolkit.html)

1. Start the VS Code editor.
2. In the Activity Bar on the side of the VS Code editor, choose the Extensions icon. This opens the Extensions view, which allows you to access the VS Code Marketplace.

[image: The Extensions icon in the VS Code Activity Bar.]

3. In the search box for Extensions, search for AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code. Choose the entry to see its details in the right pane.
4. In the right pane, choose Install.
5. Once installed, if you're prompted to restart the editor, choose Reload Required to finish installation.

After you install the Toolkit for VS Code, you should configure your credentials to enable you to access your AWS resources from within VS Code.

It appears you can easily deploy from VSCode after you install the extension.

[image]

I know the screenshot demonstrates deployment of a SAM application but I'm assuming this extension also gives you the ability to easily deploy AWS Elastic Beanstalk Web/ NodeJS Apps too.

https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/ contains all of the relevant information you need.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/welcome.html is the user guide.